# Extending my desktop across two monitors with Nvidia Geforce 8800 GT

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce

When I played my old computer before I got this one, I was able to use the horizontal span. (Nvidia Geforce 6200 I believe) However, with this new computer, using vista and the 8800, the horizontal span option is gone, and all I have is dual veiw, which doesn't suit my needs.

I play World of Warcraft on both my monitors, using CT_Viewport to keep my character and my veiwport on a single screen, while the majority of my addons lie on my other monitor. The problem with dual view is that the WoW will only stay on my primary monitor. Horizontal span would fix this easily, but there is no option for it. Any help regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is [not available in Vista](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=21267).

Comment: However, it's not available on Vista or higher.

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Unfotunately, this feature is only supported on Windows XP.

The model for display drivers was changed in Windows Vista, and nVidia and ATI were too lazy to re-implement horizontal span.
I beleive that it is still supported by Matrox video cards.